# Индексация AMP страницы

Tags: amp

ребята, подскажите, кто сталкивался с AMP, вопрос в следующем. Есть сайт на сайте полноценная страничка (статья) и эта же страничка AMP версия, так вот валидация пройдена - всё нормально, всё сделано правильно. И вопрос в следующем, через какое время эта страничка появится в поисковике, пока отображается только полноценная страничка. Сколько времени нужно гуглу на проверку? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Имеет ли ваша каноническая веб-страница связь с амп-страницей с использованием элемента amphtml?

Comment: @nikant25 да имеет, страница amp с линкой на полноценную страницу и rel="canonical", а полноценная с rel="amphtml", но уже прошло около 12 часов, а в гугле эта страничка так и не засветилась...

Comment: Проверьте веб-страницу амп на двух валидаторах: https://validator.ampproject.org/ ++ https://validator.w3.org/nu/ . Первый генерирует только амп ошибки. Второй генерирует все ошибки, поэтому исключите специфические ошибки связанные с амп, которые на самом деле есть простое несоответствие стандарту HTML5.

Comment: @nikant25, на 100% проходит оба валидатора, ну естественно во втором amp теги.

Comment: Скорее всего там какая то техническая ошибка. По моему скромному мнению это вопрос скорее всего подходит для Webmasters Help Community с полной детальной информацией о проблеме.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cпасибо за отклик, прошло 5 дней и всё заработало. собственно 5 дней понадобилось гуглу для обработки этого вопроса.